# Load csv with timestamp column to athena table

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have started using Athena Query engine on top of my S3 FILEs
some of them are timestamp format columns.

I have created a simple table with 2 columns

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(
  `date_x` timestamp, 
  `clicks` int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://aws-athena-query-results-123-us-east-1/test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1525003090')
```

I have tried to load a file and query it with Athena:
which look like that:

```
"2018-08-09 06:00:00.000",12
"2018-08-09 06:00:00.000",42
"2018-08-09 06:00:00.000",22
```

I have tried a different type format of timestamps such as DD/MM/YYYY AND YYY-MM-DD..., tried setting the time zone for each row - but none of them worked.

Each value I have tried is showing in Athena as this results:

```
        date_x  clicks
        1       12
        2       42
        3       22
```

I have tried using a CSV file with and without headers
tried using with and without quotation marks,
But all of them showing defected timestamp.
My column on Athena must be Timestamp - rather it without timezone.
Please don't offer to use STRING column or DATE columns, this is not what i need.

How should the CSV File look like so Athena will recognize the Timestamp column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the FORMAT: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

Article https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html suggests:

```
"Timestamp values in text files must be in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS, as the following timestamp value shows: 2017-05-01 11:30:59.000000 . "
```